# How to align views pager url with real page number?

Tags: 7, views, paging

When creating pager in views (D7) you get urls with query parameter like `page=X` by default. But this X does not match actual page number.

`page=1` is generated for `2` link in the paginator and so on.

Is there any way to make them the same without too much of code kung-fu or did I miss some checkbox?

Comment: This is an old issue https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1818040

Answer (score 2):

As 4k4 mentioned in the comment there is an issue for this you should check out.

In the meantime you might implement a workaround (outside of Views)

- with the help of the [Query Parameters To URL](https://www.drupal.org/project/query_parameters_to_url),
- or outside of Drupal through your server configuration and redirects.